# Run Python script on all files in the directory after a file has run, create a new folder and name the folder after the file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, file, directory

I wrote a Python script `TestData.py`that uses Pandas and NumPy to test a CSV for data anomalies. It inputs one CSV and outputs 4 new ones. For each input file that needs testing I do the following:

- Copy the name of the unknown file. In this example: `unknownfilename1.csv`
- Create a folder.
- Rename the New Folder by pasting in `unknownfilename1.csv`, removing the `.csv`
- Paste `unknownfilename1.csv` into `data = pd.read_csv("unknownfilename0.csv")`
- Drag `TestData.py` into the folder `unknownfilename1`
- Finally, run `TestData.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Import raw data
data = pd.read_csv("unknownfilename1.csv", encoding='latin-1' )

#################################################
# Over 500 lines of code using Pandas and Numpy #
#################################################

# failed at least one testcase, needs to be fixed before importing.
failed.to_csv("C:/users/path/Failed.csv", index = False)
# Output passed rows.
passed.to_csv("C:/users/path/Passed.csv", index = False)
# Ready to import.
newimpomatic.to_csv("C:/users/path/Import.csv", index = False)
# Duplicates IDs
duplicated.to_csv("C:/users/path/duplicated.csv", index = False)
```

I would like each file to be tested in:

```
C:/users/path/unknownfilename1.csv
C:/users/path/unknownfilename2.csv
C:/users/path/unknownfilename3.csv
```

To output:

```
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename1/Failed.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename1/Passed.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename1/Import.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename1/duplicated.csv

 C:/users/path/unknownfilename2/Failed.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename2/Passed.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename2/Import.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename2/duplicated.csv

 C:/users/path/unknownfilename3/Failed.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename3/Passed.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename3/Import.csv
 C:/users/path/unknownfilename3/duplicated.csv
```

If I have 100s different files in a folder. What is the easiest way to add something to my script to test all files, after each file is tested, create a new folder and then name the folder after the file that was tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Path` class in the python builtin library `pathlib` is great at this, and working with files/folder locations in general. With `glob(pattern: str)`, you can yield all matches to a particular file pattern in a directory, and iterate over those matches.

https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob

You can also use `Path` to grab the name of the file and create a new directory to place your outputted csvs.

The file below assumes it is in the same directory as all of the original csvs, but that is changeable. I call that directory `base_dir`, equivalent to what you listed as `C:/users/path/`

`/users/path/main.py`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


failed_csv = 'Failed.csv'
passed_csv = 'Passed.csv'
import_csv = 'Import.csv'
dup_csv = 'duplicated.csv'


def get_root() -> Path:
    return Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def process(csv_file: Path, out_dir: Path) -> None:
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding='latin-1')
    
    ###
    ### Do existing processing of data DataFrame
    ###

    # Save files. These print statements will show the final
    # file path for each of the output csvs.

    print(out_dir / failed_csv)  # '/users/path/my_file/Failed.csv'
    print(out_dir / passed_csv)  # '/users/path/my_file/Passed.csv'
    print(out_dir / import_csv)  # '/users/path/my_file/Import.csv'
    print(out_dir / dup_csv)     # '/users/path/my_file/duplicated.csv'

    failed.to_csv(out_dir / failed_csv, index=False)
    passed.to_csv(out_dir / passed_csv, index=False)
    newimpomatic.to_csv(out_dir / import_csv, index=False)
    duplicated.to_csv(out_dir / dup_csv, index=False)


def main(base_dir: Path) -> None:

    print(f'Processing files in {base_dir}: \n')

    n_process = 0
    for csv_file in base_dir.glob('*.csv'):
        
        # ex. csv_file = "/users/path/my_file.csv"
        
        name: str = csv_file.stem   # name = "my_file"
        
        output_dir: Path = base_dir / name  # output_dir = "/users/path/my_file"

        print(f'Creating directory "{output_dir}"')
        Path.mkdir(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

        print(f'Processing "{csv_file}"')
        process(csv_file=csv_file, out_dir=output_dir)

        print(f'Completed processing\n')
        n_process += 1

    print(f'\nProcessed {n_process} files')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = get_root()  # root = "users/path"
    main(base_dir=root)
```

Comment: This worked amazingly well, just perfect. Thank you.